# Stripe - Create Subscription (automatically) for new customers

Tags: automation, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Is there a way to automatically subscripe a new stripe customer to a "Free" tier subscription product stored in Stripe?

Reason I'm looking to do that, is that stripe customers can't "change plans" and/or "subscribe to plans" inside the "customer portal" until yoiu have created a subscription for the customer.

It's a bit annoying and I believe the customer portal should offer a "Subscribe to plan now" button, and not only "Switch plans" option once subscribed, but I won't ask for stripe to change their running system - All I need, is to subscribe a new customer to a free subscription automatically so clients can upgrade their plans in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the billing portal is a Subscription management system, it doesn't let you create any.
The intention is that you create Subscriptions - say with Checkout or Payment Links - then offer a similar portal for updating the same Subscription.

Granted both workflows are decoupled when it would seem more efficient to merge them.

Back to your question, I don't really know what you mean by 'automatically'. Your Customers surely aren't created automatically, I'm guessing you have some routine to create them on your end.

In that case, you're really answering your own question:

> how do I create a free tier Subscription?

You can just create a zero-amount Product, and create a Subscription to it for your Customer.
Or you could use a trial period using `trial_period_days` (note that in both cases your Subscription would renew immediately from a paid upgrade).
You just have to make sure you steer clear of those limitations:
https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management#customer-portal-limitations

In my mind, the main problems you have would be:
1-How do you collect payment methods ?
The portal can do it, or you might do it when you create your Customer.

2-How do you somehow make this process not look strange to the Customer ?
This refers both to the free Subscription + manual upgrade, as well as how you might have to collect the payment method (1). I don't know what your app looks like, or what you service is, but if I had to go through this ordeal as a Customer, I'd get second thoughts.